# Restriction on sum of elements

Tags: xml

I have an object that can contain several sub-objects, like this:

```
  <parent>
    <totalCandy>5</totalCandy>
    <child>
      <candy>2</candy>
    </child>
    <child>
      <candy>3</candy>
    </child>
  </parent>
```

I want the XML to validate only if the sum of the 'candy' values for all children of a parent sum to exactly the 'totalCandy' value of the parent. Can this check be done with a schema (if so, can you give me some keywords to look into?)? Or should I do it in my parser?

The XSD schema so far is as follows, but I'm not sure how to apply restrictions on the sum of child elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="parent" type="parentType"/>

<xs:complexType name="childType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="candy" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="parentType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="totalCandy" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
    <xs:element name="child" type="childType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: @JimGarrison I added the current XSD as an edit, but I'm not sure how to place restrictions on the sum of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xs:restriction` is not supported in the context of `xs:complexType`, 
and the `xs.:restriction` children like `xs:minInclusive` are only available for `xs:simpleContent`. And it makes sense:

XSD defines a schema, but what you want to do is not a restriction to the schema of an XML file, but directly to the content. If you distrust the data, leave out the summary and calculate it yourself (e.g. let an XSLT processor generate it).

Comment: I'll take this to mean "do your check in the parser". I do distrust the data, but I do know the "summary" (correct answer) ahead of time, so I need to encode it in the file so I know what to compare the sum against.